# Add CTA after every 6th list item and another CTA ad every 6th starting from number 4 (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a listing with items and i want to add two different CTA bars, which is i another container (can't change markup). I want to add the cta bars as every 6th item, but the first cta bar should start as number four (after number three). 
I've tried ".listing__item:nth-child(6n - 3)" and it works fine if i only use this cta bar but when i have another cta bar the calculation is not working.

```js
(function($) {
    $('.cta__price').detach().insertAfter(
  $('.listing.example').find('.listing__item:nth-child(6n - 3)')
 );
 $('.cta__contact').detach().insertAfter(
  $('.listing.example').find('.listing__item:nth-child(6n)')
 );
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.container.example .listing__item {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 20px);
}
.container.example .cta__item {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="contaier cta">
        <div class="cta__item cta__price">USE THE PRICE CALCULATOR</div>
        <div class="cta__item cta__contact">QUESTIONS - CALL US</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Example with my code -->
    <div class="container listing example">
        <div class="listing__item">One</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Two</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Three</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Four</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Five</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Six</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Eleven</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Twelve</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Thirteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Fourteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Fifthteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Sixteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Seventeen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Eightteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Nineteen</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Twenty</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyOne</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyTwo</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyThree</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyFour</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyFive</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentySix</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentySeven</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyEight</div>
        <div class="listing__item">TwentyNine</div>
        <div class="listing__item">Thirty</div>
        <div class="listing__item">ThirtyOne</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 7n instead of 6n, it works as you want it.